# How do i create a new column in my dataframe based on conditional matches between two respective other columns: R

Tags: r, string

I need a character string(?) match from two columns to be matched against *each other*. If each of those strings from those two columns match, then i want a value in the newly created column to equal 1; If they do not match, then i want the value in the new column to equal 0.

I need to do this for multiple string matches between the two columns which, if matched, will each assign a value of 1 in the third column.

Please help. I am a noob.

**Example:**
I want all instances where "stimuli/240_123" from column 'A' matches "stimuli/hightone" from column 'B'in the same row
**As well as**
all instances where "stimuli/240_321" from column 'A' matches "stimuli/lowtone" from column 'B' in the same row
to each give a value of 1 in the 3rd column 'C'.

**And** all other values that do not meet those matches to equal 0 in column 'C'

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Please check the `ifelse` function where you can define conditions. These can also be used to create new columns like `df$C <- ifelse(df$A == "..." & df$B == "...", 1, 0)`

Comment: Thanks. So if i were to add multiple conditions, where would i put those? in the same ifelse argument?

Comment: Yes. In your case it would be an or condition: ifelse((df$A == ... & df$B == ...) | (df$A == ... & df$B == ...), 1, 0)

Comment: Exactly. Worked.